# Using a properties file as a UI Mapping in java:

Tags: java, user-interface, properties, selenium, dictionary

So, I'm going through the selenium test design considerations documentation and I have a question about the UI Mapping section found here:
http://seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.html#ui-mapping

They suggest to create a properties file like so:

```
admin.username = loginForm:tbUsername
admin.loginbutton = loginForm:btnLogin
admin.events.createnewevent = adminHomeForm:_activitynew
admin.events.cancel = addEditEventForm:_IDcancel
admin.events.viewoldevents = adminHomeForm:_activityold
```

That maps an html object to a keyword

Then they will use it like so:

```
selenium.type(admin.username, "xxxxxxxx");
```

However, from what I've seen about the Properties Object it works very similar to a hashtable. Now I'm loading my properties file as shown here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html
under the create and load default properties section

So todo the same statement in the docs I need todo:

```
selenium.type(loadedProps.get(admin.username), "xxxxxxx");
```

which isn't bad, just not as readable as their example, so my question is how do I load the properties file so I can use the keywords like they do.
Also, I'm thinking about going with Page Object Design Pattern, so if I did go that way, would I define a PageObject Base class, which loads
the properties file and then all the page object classes that extends the base will have access to the properties, is this sound reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in *java*, since '.' has meaning as an operator, you can't make it look exactly like their example (not sure what they were getting at).  you could do something like:

setup code:

```
public class Config {
  public static String admin_username;

  static {
    Properties props = ...;
    admin_username = props.getProperty("admin.username");
  }
}
```

usage code:

```
import static Config.*;

selenium.type(admin_username, "xxxxxxxx");
```

if you really got crazy, you could load the Config class using reflection (to remove the boilerplate in the "static" block).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't think it's good practise, but if you want to use it, hey, it's your call.

```
public class AdminUiMap {
    public String username;

    public UiMap(String fileName) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream(fileName));

        this.username = props.getProperty("admin.username");
    }
}
```

Then, in your test setup, you could do

```
AdminUiMap admin = new AdminUiMap("adminLocators.properties");
```

and then you'd really write

```
selenium.type(admin.username, "xxxxxxxx");
```

---

The second option: see [this doc](http://svn.openqa.org/fisheye/browse/~raw,r=trunk/selenium/trunk/src/main/resources/core/scripts/ui-doc.html). It's a pretty straightforward manual, I'll just point out the single paragraph that is specifically for Selenium RC:

> For the Selenium RC, you have two options. The map file may be
>   included in the `user-extensions.js` file specified at startup with the
>   `-userExtensions` switch. Or, you may load it dynamically with the variant of the `setUserExtensionJs` command in your driver language,
>   before the browser is started.